# How to read_csv a zstd-compressed file using python-polars

Tags: python, python-polars, zstd, compressed-files

In contrast to `pandas`, polars doesn't natively support reading zstd compressed csv files.

How can I get polars to read a csv compressed file, for example using `xopen`?

I've tried this:

```py
from xopen import xopen
import polars as pl

with xopen("data.csv.zst", "r") as f:
    d = pl.read_csv(f)
```

but this errors with:

```
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Expecting to be able to downcast into bytes from read result.: 
   PyDowncastError
```

Comment: I don't know if polar supports this but in Python you can specifiy an entry in a zip file with a path-like object like this: `zipfile.Path('data.csv.zst', 'data.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

One needs to `xopen` the file in binary mode `"rb"`, then it works:

```py
from xopen import xopen
import polars as pl

with xopen("data.csv.zst", "rb") as f:
    d = pl.read_csv(f)
```

Beware that the entire file will be read into memory before parsing, even if you immediately use only a subset of columns/rows.

Answer (score 1):

> polars doesn't natively support reading compressed csv files.

This is not really true. We support decompression for `zlib` and `gzip`. You can make a feature request for `zstd`, then we can look into supporting that as well.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think that's documented here (yet): https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html I've opened a feature request: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9283